# Why should registered port numbers not be used as public ports?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port, ports

Registered Ports  (1024 - 49, 151) are port numbers that gets registered with IANA for public use.

Assume I have a popular application like discord, running on some port using a different protocol named 'xxx'.

- Do I have to register the port number for IANA?
- If not then what's the purpose to register a port number in IANA if
  everybody can use any port and in which case a port conflict occurs?
- Why does a port conflict occurs when port numbers are used publicly?
- If a port is registered , then how one knows if it's registered
  already or if it's unregistered, is there any database for it?

Any practical examples will be helpful to understand.

Comment: Did you try googling `iana registered numbers database`? Did you check IANA documentation about port registrations? Which answers exactly are unclear?

Comment: @Peregrino69 the documentation part is not easy for me to understand as I'm just learning about ports. Yes I did search but I didn't see the page numbers below in that website as I only saw the first few protocol numbers.

Comment: Heh - welcome to the Wonderful World of IT :-) The language is tough to understand at first, but once you get the hang of it it gets easier. The reserved ports are "defaults", nothing forces you to use them. For example listening to SSH on some other port than 22 is a common practice. See @harrymc's answer. [Here's](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-cotton-tsvwg-iana-ports-00.html) IETF document regarding registrations. Note that it's expired and updated since, but the basics haven't changed that much, and the doc contains link for updated info.

Comment: For the most part you don't need to care about registering ports, unless you are deploying major internet backbone stuff that needs everyone to know and agree that that port is used for your thing and nothing else. Past that it's a "gentleman's agreement" that you don't knowingly use ports that might be commonly assigned to another application.

Comment: Really Thanks for your answers. They are helpful for my understanding of ports as a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common misconception about the IANA port registration.

The only reason this list exists is to avoid conflicts with
well-known software.

Nothing stops you from using any one port from the list if you have
not installed the software that uses it by default. And even then,
you may set that software to use another port (if possible).

I wouldn't advice installing a web-server on your computer and using
port 80 for something else beside serving web-pages, but you
certainly can, as long as you know what you are doing.
This is many times done on purpose, see for example
[Honeypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)).

Comment: THanks. But can you explain this line plz -  ' The only reason this list exists is to avoid conflicts with well-known software ' . What conflicts and how it'll happen . I'm a real beginner . sry if the answer for my question is already in your answer.

Comment: Two listeners on the same port doesn't work, so the list helps to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I still need to get some knowledge about real-world working of ports.